# For Testing Purposes, How to Change the Android/iOS Device Token (which is used for Push Notifications)

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-firebase

Using a React-Native library, e.g. @react-native-firebase/messaging, or React-Native-Notifications, an App can request to get updates for the device's token.

@react-native-firebase/messaging: `firebase.messaging().onTokenRefresh()`
React-Native-Notifications Ver2: `NotificationsAndroid.setRegistrationTokenUpdateListener()`
React-Native-Notifications Ver3: `Notifications.android.commands.refreshToken();`

How can I test such code? In other words, **how can I force (for testing purposes) the change of the device's token (on an emulator/simulator or a physical iOS/Android device)?**